# Cannot get Maven working on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, maven

I am entirely new to Maven, so baby steps are much appreciated! I've looked at many tutorials for getting Maven to run on Windows (7), and they all basically give the same instructions. Download **latest JDK** (in my case 1.7.0_25), download **latest version of maven** (in my case 3.1.0), extract maven to some path without spaces, and edit **System variables** in the Environment Variables window.

Here is what I have updated the relevant variables to look like:

```
User variables for jameswe
TEMP        %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP         %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

System Variables
JAVA_HOME   C:\jdk1.7.0_25
MAVEN_HOME  C:\Users\jameswe\Maven
Path        existingValue;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

I've restarted my computer, and still when I type the command line `mvn -version` I get the error:

`'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I am on a work computer, which does have a **firewall** that prevents us from going on certain sites (gaming, social media, etc), our Windows firewall has something called an Active Domain Network operated by our company. And a **proxy** test responded that I do have a proxy up. I'm not really sure what all this means/if it's relevant, but if someone could explain what I need to do here, that would be fantastic!

Thank you all!

Comment: This looks more like a Windows question than a Maven question. 

At the command prompt (type `cmd` into the start menu), enter `echo %PATH%` and confirm the Maven directory appears in the output. 

If it does, then confirm the Maven directory *as it appears in the output* (you can copy-paste it) actually contains a file called `mvn.bat` or `mvn.exe`.

I'm guessing that either the Maven directory is missing from the PATH variable (even though you believe otherwise), or that the Maven directory included in the PATH variable is incorrect.

Comment: I agree: it can't be on the path. You don't have to use MAVEN_HOME variable. Why not try SET Path = C:\Users\jameswe\Maven\bin;%Path% and see the result. BTW is you change Environment Variables, you must reopen a new cmdprompt (rebooting not necessary)

Comment: Problem was with the path, I wasn't really thinking about what the '\bin' meant. There was another folder separating the two, works great now. Thanks!

Comment: If anyone is having issues with setting up maven in Windows, try this first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830646/cmd-cannot-find-mvn-command. There is a tutorial there.

Comment: @JuniorM Although they are related, these questions are not duplicates. AFAICT, the setup as described in this question, already matches the answers of the linked question.