# cmd cannot find mvn command

Tags: windows, maven, path-variables

I just installed Maven and added the `\bin` directory of maven to my path variables. When I try to use the `mvn` command in the Command Prompt I just get a message:

> mvn: command not found

Everything else I found on here did not help yet.

### Edit:

I used https://maven.apache.org/install.html to install maven.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\mvn.cmd
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Comment: The project could also be updated to use the [maven wrapper](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-wrapper-plugin/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have included the file in the path:

```
C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\mvn.cmd
```

That is not good. The PATH environment variable should only include a path to where files, like exe and cmd's can be found.

Adapt your PATH to read like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin
```

(so remove the `\mvn.cmd`). Make sure to start a new command prompt to verify if your path settings are correct.

See [How can I set user environmental variables (such as PATH) from a non-administrator account on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/165909/how-can-i-set-user-environmental-variables-such-as-path-from-a-non-administrat) to find the correct Windows dialog to adapt the settings among [many more](https://superuser.com/search?q=set+path+%5Bwindows%5D).

Answer (score 6):

Following [this tutorial by mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/), I was able to get this to work on Windows 10 (v10.0.15063):

1. Install JDK and setup `JAVA_HOME` system variable

   [image]
2. Download Maven zip, extract it and setup `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` system variables to point to root maven folder (without \bin)

   [image]
3. Update `PATH` system variable to include `%M2_HOME%\bin` (this is what will let you run "mvn" in Command Prompt).

   [image]
4. Open Command Prompt (cmd.exe) and execute `mvn -version`

---

You can download Maven (apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.zip) [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi), if you don't have it already.

The Java SDK (jdk-8u144-windows-x64.exe) can be downloaded from Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is my working maven configuration on Windows 10.  Was more cumbersome to configure on W10 than on WXP or W7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. I installed Maven and added the \bin directory of maven to my path variables in  **`System Variables`**, so I can only use `MAVEN` commands using admin rights (run cmd in windows as administrator)

I solved this by creating all under **`User variables`** (including the PATH variable).